# find the fifth 8_connected neighbors around pixle

Tags: matlab

I work on fingerprint image. to binary image I want to look for `8_connected` neighbors around of my point and then selected the fifth `8_connected` neighbor. I don't know how can write `matlab` code for find fifth  `8_connected` neighbors. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Convert image to binary matrix as you mentioned. Assuming your matrix' name is `A`, you can follow the code below:

```
A = magic(10); % Example matrix of values
index = [5,8]; % Example index
connected_8  = A(index(1)-1:index(1)+1 , index(2)-1:index(2)+1);
connected_8(2,2) = NaN; % Center value is Not a Neighbor ;)
fifthNeighbor = connected_8(2,3)
```

The index of the fifth neighbor depends on wether you read indices row wise or column wise.

Note: If you go through all indices, you will get an "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." error. To avoid this you must either exclude boundary indices, or design logic to handle the boundaries. Let me know if you need help. However, I believe this answers your question.